# codeigniter join changing id from one table's id to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this code for an active record query in codeigniter:

```
$this->db->join('user', 'user.id = purchase_req.owner_id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('user.employer_id', $User->employer_id);
$Purchase_req = $this->Purchase_req->find();
```

In a view without the join statement, `$Purchase_req->id` would return the actual purchase request id. In the view with the join, `$Purchase_req->id` returns the user id. How can I join the tables together, and still get the purchase request id, instead of it changing to the user.id?

Comment: Can you clear it up a bit? What you want to get and what you get now?

Comment: What I am getting now with `$Purchase_req->id` is the user.id.

What I want to get, and what I get without the join statement is the purchase_req.id when I call `$Purchase_req->id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id you want to achieve is the ambiguous for mysql because the both tables have the id columns therefore when you tries to access the `$Purchase_req->id` it will return the last id column which is from the `purchase_req` table you need to assingn the unique aliases for the same columns in the joined table like

```
$this->db->select('`user`.*,`purchase_req`.*,`user`.id AS user_id')
$this->db->join('user', 'user.id = purchase_req.owner_id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('user.employer_id', $User->employer_id);
$Purchase_req = $this->Purchase_req->find();
```

Now when you echo `$Purchase_req->user_id` it will return the user.id

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This solved my problem, and made it a lot clearer to me how this is working.